# Setting arbitrary color in pseudocolor plot with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add separate colors for two (or more) specific values in color plot and color bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10466730/add-separate-colors-for-two-or-more-specific-values-in-color-plot-and-color-ba)

I've got an array of values and I'd like to plot these using pcolor in matplotlib. I'm using the color map 'YlOrRd' and it works fine - but I'd like to use the color map for all values other than zero. That is, all values not 0, should use the color map - I'd like 0 to be black.

currently I'm using, for my numpy array of values 'x'.

```
pcolor(x,cmap=cm.YlOrRd)
```

is there a way to arbitrarily fix all values in array x that are 0 to black?

Thanks,
Dave.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are two ways to do it. One by creating your own `colormap`, and one by using a `masked array`. Say we have:

```
import matplotlib
from pylab import *

data = np.arange(-50, 50).reshape(10, 10)
data = np.abs(data)
pcolor(data, cmap=cm.YlOrRd)
show()
```

This produces:
[image]
Now we do the same thing, but create a list called `colors` that has the same values as `cm.YlOrRd`, apart from the `0` entry, which we set to black (`0,0,0` in rgb). Then we use `LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list` to actually make the colormap:

```
import matplotlib
from pylab import *

data = np.arange(-50, 50).reshape(10, 10)
data = np.abs(data)
colors = [(0,0,0)] + [(cm.YlOrRd(i)) for i in xrange(1,256)]
new_map = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('new_map', colors, N=256)
pcolor(data, cmap=new_map)
savefig('map.png')
show()
```

This produces the same plot, but zero values are black:

[image]
Here is the other way using masked arrays, its a bit more involved, comments in the code explain the steps:

```
from pylab import *
import numpy.ma as ma

data=np.arange(-50,50).reshape(10,10)
data=np.abs(data)
#create a mask where only values=0 are true:
mask = data == 0
#create a masked array by combining our mask and data:
mx = ma.masked_array(data, mask)
#set masked values in cm.YlOrRd to 'black'
cm.YlOrRd.set_bad(color='black', alpha=None)
# pcolor(data,cmap=cm.YlOrRd)
#we must use pcolormesh instead of pcolor, as pcolor does not draw masked values at all
pcolormesh(mx,cmap=cm.YlOrRd)
show()
```

This produces the same plot as immediately above.

There is a potential difference between these methods, the first method will round down data values and apply the appropriate color, while the second method will only set values equal to 0 to black (ie. 0.001 will not be masked, so will be the appropriate `cm.YlOrRd` color). The main advantage of the second is that you can mask out entries totally arbitrarily.